# get all changed in sitecollection using powershell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, export

I need to get all changes on my sitecollection , sites,webs,lists and folders and to export them into cmp files.
so i used this code to get the changes :

```
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"

    function global:Get-ChangeLog($url, $minutes)
    {
     trap [Exception] {
      write-error $("ERROR: " + $_.Exception.GetType().FullName);
      write-error $("ERROR: " + $_.Exception.Message);

      continue;   
     }

     $s = new-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($url);
     $startTime = [System.DateTime]::Now.Subtract([System.TimeSpan]::FromMinutes($minutes));

     $db_id = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPContentDatabase].getmethod("get_Id");
     $getContentDBName = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPContentDatabase].getmethod("get_Name") 
     $result_id = $db_id.Invoke($s.ContentDatabase, "instance,public", $null, $null, $null);

     $db_CurrentChangeToken = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPContentDatabase].getmethod("get_CurrentChangeToken");
     $result_CurrentChangeToken = $db_CurrentChangeToken.Invoke($s.ContentDatabase, "instance,public", $null, $null, $null);

     $startToken = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPChangeToken([Microsoft.SharePoint.SPChangeCollection+CollectionScope]::ContentDB, $result_id.ToString(), $startTime);

     $changeQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPChangeQuery($False, $False);
     $changeQuery.User = $True;
     $changeQuery.ContentType = $True;
     $changeQuery.Add = $True;
     $changeQuery.Delete = $True;
     $changeQuery.Field = $True;
     $changeQuery.File = $True;
     $changeQuery.Folder = $True;
     $changeQuery.Group = $True;
     $changeQuery.GroupMembershipAdd = $True;
     $changeQuery.GroupMembershipDelete = $True;
     $changeQuery.Item = $True;
     $changeQuery.List = $True;
     $changeQuery.Move = $True;
     $changeQuery.Rename = $True;
     $changeQuery.Site = $True;
     $changeQuery.SystemUpdate = $True;
     $changeQuery.Update = $True;

     $changeQuery.ChangeTokenStart = $startToken;
     $changeQuery.ChangeTokenEnd = $result_CurrentChangeToken;

     $db_GetChanges = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPContentDatabase].getmethod("GetChanges", [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPChangeQuery]);
     $result_GetChanges = $db_GetChanges.Invoke($s.ContentDatabase, "instance,public", $null, $changeQuery, $null);

     $myArray ="User","ContentType","Add","Delete","Field","File","Folder","Group","GroupMembershipAdd","GroupMembershipDelete","Item","List","Move","Rename","Site","SystemUpdate","Update"

     foreach ($type in $myArray){

     write-Output  "********************"$type "********************"
     write-Output $result_GetChanges | Where-Object { $_.ChangeType -eq $type };

    # $detail= Get-SPSite $url | Get-SPWeb  -Limit ALL | %{$_.Lists} | ?{$_.ID -eq $result_GetChanges.ListId} | ft Title, ParentWebURL, RootFolder
    # write-Output $detail


     $s.Dispose();
    }
    }

    Get-ChangeLog -url http://srvdev -minutes 60000  >log.txt
```

The problem of this one is look for changes on content data base like sql query , it take so much time and the log is too long , so is there a way to have the result with a faster way ?

this is an exemple of the log:

```
WebId        : 33c24466-09d0-48d8-97f6-ac6b9865a57c
ListId       : 075504ed-42c0-4b7d-bf4b-166a552c657a
UniqueId     : 9aca9026-64e1-4dde-91e8-d7dd31e15d8c
BeforeListId : 075504ed-42c0-4b7d-bf4b-166a552c657a
AfterListId  : 075504ed-42c0-4b7d-bf4b-166a552c657a
Id           : 7484
BeforeId     : 7484
AfterId      : 7484
ChangeType   : SystemUpdate
SiteId       : cf6e0902-ddd7-4a6b-9af9-57da2620948b
Time         : 09/06/2016 11:23:40
ChangeToken  : 1;0;82f60677-02db-4927-bcbf-db35d9370833;636010682197630000;1686
               648
```

Comment: Hi @Imen , Are you tried to use  Auditing Reports within site collection audit settings page and enabling all auditable actions. I think it's simpler than this method , Or you need to use PowerShell for specific purpose !

Comment: Hi M.Qassas , ya thats what i need , the probleme with site collection audit setting is that i have to choose the list/site manually , but me i have to automate all that