# Get the Report of Site Collection Changes without enabling Auditing

Tags: development, central-administration, ssom, sharepoint-farm, farm-admin

- I have come ac-crossed to annoying requirement , Where I need to get
  the report of changes made in site collection with out enabling
  "Audit" feature in SharePoint 2013
- Can any one help me or guide me in achieving this.

Comment: You can use powershell  please check this for reference https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/187174/get-all-changed-in-sitecollection-using-powershell